# How do you present without showing notes to audience on MacBook Air single screen

Tags: google-slides, mac, zoom.us, google-meet

How do I present a Google Slides presentation via Zoom on a MacBook Air (2021) while viewing the notes only on my screen. I can also utilize Google Meet format; however, I am not familiar with that option. I am open to suggestions and work arounds! My slide presentation opens in Keynote and or Google Slides and neither seem compatible with Zoom. I do not have a PowerPoint version of this presentation which would make this process simple.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se].  What web browser are you using? (Some Google apps features are only available in Chrome, are you open to use Chrome ?) Are you using the Zoom Meeting (the installable app) or the Zoom "online" (the web app)?

Answer (score 0):

Google Slides has a presenter view. This shows the presentation in presentation mode in the current web browser tab and opens a second window showing the presenter view.

Put each the presenter view and the presentation view next to each other.

Then in your online presentation tool, Zoom, Google Meet, or any other that supports sharing a window instead the full screen, set the share screen settings to share the window showing the presentation.

Another option is to use the Google Slides mobile app to see your presentation notes while presenting on a Google Meet meeting.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to only share a portion of your screen on Zoom. Click the Share button in the meeting window > in the sharing options select "Advanced" at the top of the window > select "Portion of Screen."

Once this is done you can just adjust the box to exclude the presenter notes in the view.